# Google Geocode encodeAdress()

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, google-maps-api-3, geocode

Having problems ***getting lat & lng*** from googles response.

Google is responding some xml looking like :

```
 "location" : {
           "lat" : 53.55914120,
           "lng" : 10.00923520
        },
```

I´m parsing this with `var  r = results[0].geometry.location;`

and alerting (r) says:

```
(53.55914120,10.00923520)
```

***now the problem*** :

When i try  `var  r = results[0].geometry.location.lat;`

and alerting (r) says:

```
function (){return this[a]}
```

so ***my question is:***

when  `r =  results[0].geometry.location;` r = `(53.55914120,10.00923520)`

how do i get lat and lng from it ?

```
alert(r[0]r[1])  <!-- doesn´t work, returns "undefined" -->
```

***or***

how can i store lat & lng in two different variables from the beginning,

Thanks in advance
i expected `var  r = results[0].geometry.location.lat;` but that doesn´t work

Comment: What do `r[0]` and `r[1]` give you?

Comment: ah didn´t mention, sry --- returns "undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
```